One question about exponential martingale inequality at a paper of Ann. of Math.
I saw a strange inequality about martingales:

If $\operatorname{M}\left(s,t\right)$ is an continuous $L^{2}$ martingale start at $s$, $\left[\operatorname{M}\right]\left(s,t\right)$ is its quadratic variation.
$\eta \in (0,\frac{\alpha}{2}]$.
Can we obtain such inequality
$$
P(\sup_{\,t\ \ge\ s}\left(\operatorname{M}\left(s,t\right)
 - \frac{\alpha}{2\eta}\,
\left[\operatorname{M}\right]\left(s,t\right)\right) \geq
   K\left\vert{\mathcal F}_{s}\right) \leq
   \exp\left(\operatorname{M}\left(s,s\right)
 - \frac{\alpha K}{\eta}\right),
$$
by standard exponential martingala estimate ?.

I saw it on Hairer, M., Mattingly, J.C.: Ergodicity of the 2D Navier–Stokes equations with degenerate stochastic forcing. Ann.
of Math. (2) 164 (3), 993–1032 (2006) 1027,proof of Lemma 4.10
https://annals.math.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/annals-v164-n3-p07.pdf
Well, if we assume all the condition to be fine, such that $\exp(\frac{\alpha}{\eta}\operatorname{M}\left(s,t\right)
 - \frac{\alpha^2}{2\eta^2}\,
\left[\operatorname{M}\right]\left(s,t\right))$ is an true maringale, and we can obtain that
$$
P(\sup_{\,t\ \ge\ s}\left(\operatorname{M}\left(s,t\right)
 - \frac{\alpha}{2\eta}\,
\left[\operatorname{M}\right]\left(s,t\right)\right) \geq
   K\left\vert{\mathcal F}_{s}\right) 
= 
$$
$$
P(\sup_{\,t\ \ge\ s}\left(\frac{\alpha}{\eta}\operatorname{M}\left(s,t\right) - \frac{\alpha^2}{2\eta^2}\,
\left[\operatorname{M}\right]\left(s,t\right)\right) \geq
  \frac{\alpha}{\eta}K\left\vert{\mathcal F}_{s}\right)
=
$$
$$
P(\sup_{\,t\ \ge\ s}\exp \left(\frac{\alpha}{\eta}\operatorname{M}\left(s,t\right) - \frac{\alpha^2}{2\eta^2}\,
\left[\operatorname{M}\right]\left(s,t\right)\right) \geq
  \exp (\frac{\alpha}{\eta}K) \left\vert{\mathcal F}_{s}\right) \le  \exp\left(\operatorname{M}\left(s,s\right)
 - \frac{\alpha K}{\eta}\right),
$$
in form at least.
we know that if X is a martingale, then by the Maximal inequality, we have
$$
\lambda P(\sup_{0 \le s \le t} X_s \ge \lambda) \le E[X_t^+]
$$
but the ineuqlity on the paper seems to be
$$
\lambda P(\sup_{s \ge 0} |X_s| \ge \lambda | {\mathcal F}_0) \le |X_0| \qquad P-a.s
$$
But it is also strange, the form is not exactly same, and it is also a question whether this inequality holds.
